# griffon lazybones cannot create griffon-swing-groovy project

Tags: java, swing, groovy, griffon, lazybones

I am following this guide [Griffon Guide 2.12](http://griffon-framework.org/guide/2.12.0/)

I am stuck at 2.2.1. Creating a Project in the line
**$ lazybones create griffon-swing-groovy console**
I get the following errors:

```
lazybones create griffon-swing-groovy console                                          ~
Creating project from template griffon-swing-groovy (latest) in 'console'

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.configuredInputStream(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1978)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.newInputStream(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1991)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.withInputStream(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1657)
        at uk.co.cacoethes.lazybones.commands.PackageDownloader$_downloadPackage_closure1.doCall(PackageDownloader.groovy:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:292)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:439)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods.withStream(IOGroovyMethods.java:1316)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.withOutputStream(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:1627)
        at uk.co.cacoethes.lazybones.commands.PackageDownloader.downloadPackage(PackageDownloader.groovy:32)
        at uk.co.cacoethes.lazybones.commands.PackageDownloader$downloadPackage.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:138)
        at uk.co.cacoethes.lazybones.commands.CreateCommand.doExecute(CreateCommand.groovy:89)
        at uk.co.cacoethes.lazybones.commands.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.groovy:30)
        at uk.co.cacoethes.lazybones.LazybonesMain.main(LazybonesMain.groovy:89)
```

I am using the following environment for developing

1. Windows 7 Ultimate
2. Babun shell
3. SDK version SDKMAN 5.5.12+269
4. Lazybones

   lazybones list                                                                         ~
   Available templates in griffon/griffon-lazybones-templates

   ```
   griffon-javafx-groovy
   griffon-javafx-java
   griffon-javafx-kotlin
   griffon-lanterna-groovy
   griffon-lanterna-java
   griffon-pivot-groovy
   griffon-pivot-java
   griffon-plugin
   griffon-swing-groovy
   griffon-swing-java
   ```
5. Gradle

gradle -v
Gradle 4.3 
Build time:   2017-10-30 15:43:29  UTC Revision:c684c202534c4138b51033b52d871939b8d38d72 
Groovy:2.4.12
Ant:Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:1.8.0_144 (Oracle Corporation 25.144-b01)
OS:Windows 7 6.1 x86

I downloaded the templates manually also 
The following are available in .lazybones/templates

- griffon-javafx-groovy-template-1.9.1
- griffon-javafx-java-template-1.9.1
- griffon-plugin-template-1.9.1
- griffon-swing-groovy-template-1.9.1
- griffon-swing-java-template-1.9.1

I am still unable to create any project using lazybones.I am not able to understand the problem that I am getting.

Thanks in advance,

Vanlal

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: no am not behind a proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's odd, I can successfully create an application using the latest versions of all tools, starting from scratch as witnessed by

```
[tmp]> ls -l ~/.lazybones/templates/
[tmp]> lazybones --version
Lazybones version 0.8.3
[tmp]> gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-10-30 15:43:29 UTC
Revision:     c684c202534c4138b51033b52d871939b8d38d72

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_144 (Oracle Corporation 25.144-b01)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.12.5 x86_64

[tmp]> lazybones create griffon-swing-groovy sample
Creating project from template griffon-swing-groovy (latest) in 'sample'
Define value for 'group' [org.example]: 

 ... snip snip ...

Project created in sample!
[tmp]> ls -l ~/.lazybones/templates/
total 1024
-rw-r--r--+ 1 aalmiray  staff   510K Oct 31 18:28 griffon-swing-groovy-1.12.0.zip
[tmp]>
```

It's worth mentioning that the latest version of the `griffon-swing-groovy` template is 1.12.0. You may specify a version number when creating the application, such as

```
lazybones create griffon-swing-groovy 1.12.0 sample
```

Comment: When i use this command lazybones create griffon-swing-groovy 1.12.0 sample , it is working now..

Comment: Where is the sample folder located?

Comment: I got it , it was under C:\Users\vanlal\.babun\cygwin\home\vanlal, I was searching under  C:\Users\vanlal\

Comment: In this case `sample` stands for the name of the project you want to create. You can pick any name :-)